# Capturing multiple usernames

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working in an excel file which will be circulated to many users to get their approvals ( username as evidence ) . So I created a dropdown menu, if the user give yes then , the respective username need to be captured as approval evidence.
[image]

The VBA I used , refer below

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    'GetUserName = Environ$("username")
    'or
    GetUserName = Application.UserName
End Function
```

and in the cell i used =Getusername() as property

Now the real problem, assume I am one of the approver giving "yes" for approval, the above VBA and formula capture my username as evidence. Then I am mailing the excel file(which i gave yes and my username captured as evidence) to another approver, While he opening the excel file , the approval given by me changing and capturing the current username (the another approver username) as evidence. I dont know how to avoid this conflict.

Solution I am expecting, overall three approvers need to approve the excel file, and their corresponding username have to be captured as evidence.

Experts help is needed

Comment: When opening the workbook then need to check every `combobox` through a loop. If any `combobox` value is yes then disable that `combobox` so that other user can not change that `combobox` value.

Comment: You cannot use a UDF for this - you need to use (eg) a worksheet_change event instead.  Once populated the value needs to be static.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you please provide a sample code

Comment: How are you currently capturing the "yes" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Williams correctly says, you need to capture the username as a static value. In a nutshell, you need to define a destination cell for each combobox, then use something along the lines of

```
DestinationCell.Value = Application.UserName
```

Here is one straightforward, simple approach:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim DestinationCell As Range
    
    Set DestinationCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Yes" Then DestinationCell.Value = Application.UserName

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can define the destination cell in relation to the `LinkedCell` of the combobox, like this:

```
Set DestinationCell = ActiveSheet.Range(ComboBox1.LinkedCell).Offset(0, -2)
```